# Running Tkinter on docker container

Tags: python, docker, tkinter

I am new to using docker and I am currently learning how to build a docker image and run it. I successfully managed to build my docker image, however, I am getting this error when running the image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: Error loading shared library libtk8.6.so: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine3.8 
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ] 
CMD [ "gui.py" ]
```

Requirements.txt:

```
gspread
oauth2client
fpdf
networkx
```

I am trying to run a Tkinter app in docker. How can I resolve this? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Running interactive GUI applications is tricky to set up and only works at all on some specific platforms.  You'll probably find this much easier to run without Docker involved, maybe in a Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `package tk` is missing, hope this solves your problem. Install `tk` package for `alpine` from your Dockerfile. Modify your dockerfile to install it like below,

```
FROM python:alpine3.8 
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add tk
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ] 
CMD [ "gui.py" ]
```

If still there are any missing packages just add them using `RUN apk add <package1> <package2>`

Comment: Are you sure this works? My subsequent command `docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --net=host image_name python -m tkinter` ended up with error `$?` as 139. Even when switching to `FROM python:3-alpine` results the same. How shall I debug? By the way, the `FROM python:3-slim` & `RUN apt install python3-tk` would work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and the only thing that fixed it was installing tkinter using the following:
RUN apk update && apk add tk

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer.